# Integrate CDT fuctionality to Eclipse Product

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde

I have created an Eclipse plugin that shows an XML file as a tree(a simple functionality). I can export a product with this plugin integrated without any problems.
However, I would like to add CDT support to this product as well to get a product with both my own plugin and CDT capabilities.

I tried to export my plugin as an Eclipse feature or p2 repository and install it into a CDT product. Although it works, if users go to "Help -> About Eclipse IDE", they can see the information about "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers". I want the CDT and my plugin to be a part of the final product so that I can change product settings like its splash screen, not my plugin be a part of CDT if that makes any sense.

I also tried to add all the CDT-related plugins to the dependencies of product, feature, and plugin but could not get it to work.

Moreover, I thought about developing the CDT and changing the source code but I would like to consider this as a last resort.

How can I achieve such a goal? Is there anything that I have missed during the process? Is there any alternative way to tackle such a problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create your own product including the various existing features you want to use - this is too broad for a SO answer, [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html) covers it. Note that [tag:tycho] is the only supported way to build products, features, and plug-ins these days.

Comment: tbh I was hoping to find a way to gather all the functionalities of CDT into a feature so that I could add it to the product the same way that I am adding my own feature(containing my plugin) to it. So far, I have added all the CTD-related features that Eclipse can find when adding a feature to the content list on the product editor page but it doesn't seem enough.  On a side note, I always exported the product using the export wizard on Eclipse; I will look into Tycho. tnx @greg-449

Comment: Normally if you already a product you should be able to add additional features from the Eclipse repositories too it. I don't use CDT so I don't know if it has any special requirements.

Comment: The product and feature of the _Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers_ can be found [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages) as `org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp` (in case you want adapt for your product).